# MQTT publisher of message

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto, broker

I'm trying to run an MQTT broker and I want to store the published data, but I need to know which user sent the message so I can store payload for each user and study them later. The problem is when two different user try to publish message on same topic I can not tell whose data it is. Is there a way to figure out the publisher of a message? I'm using Mosquitto btw.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you don't.

MQTT messages do not contain any information about the user or client that sent it, unless you choose to encode it in the message (as part of the payload for v3.x or alternatively in the header properties for v5.0)

Longer answer:

Some MQTT brokers have plugin APIs that may allow you access to more meta data for a message. You may be able to write a plugin that will take the message + the meta data and then store them. Last time I looked, mosquitto's plugin API was only for writing authentication plugins, and did not give access to the messages themselves. But a different broker may allow this.

Comment: "Last time I looked" - I don't think that's the case any more as per [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/plugins/payload-modification); but I have not checked if user info is available to the callback function.